# buffer-file-name can return propertized text?

Tags: string, text-properties

Once upon a time I was surprised to see `buffer-file-name` sometimes return propertized text like `#("/tmp/foo" 1 4 (face flx-highlight-face))` instead of `"/tmp/foo"`.

I got in the habit of defensively "cleansing" when I need the filename as a simple string, e.g.:

```
(and (buffer-file-name)
     (substring-no-properties (buffer-file-name)))
```

---

Thinking about this more recently, the `flx-highlight-face` suggests this might (?) be a little bug in `flx-ido-mode` -- maybe it ought to strip the properties?

One tiny question is, should I report this as a bug?  I think I can self-answer: Yes; worst case they can explain why I'm wrong. :)

My real question is: How broadly do I need to keep this in mind? Is `buffer-file-name` just one of many Emacs functions like this?  Every time I think "string", should I slap myself and say hey, never assume an Emacs Lisp string is "simple", it could always have properties?

Comment: How does [`flx`](https://github.com/lewang/flx/blob/master/flx.el) affect `buffer-file-name`? Don't see anything to suggest it'd do that.

Comment: Although I don't understand exactly how, yet, the moving parts also include `ido-find-file` and `flx-ido-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report it as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Emacs-devel will let you know if they think it is not.

To report it you will need to anyway need to narrow it down - show a recipe to repro what you see.

Trying to come up with that minimal recipe you will find out where/how whatever code is propertizing the string. As comments to your question have indicated, that does not come from `buffer-file-name` itself.

The first step is to try to repro it when starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file).

---

To your broader question: No, you generally do not need to worry about unexpected propertization of strings.  However, whenever text is picked up from a buffer you can expect to look out for it perhaps having text properties. That's why there are functions such as `buffer-substring-no-properties`: because it is so common for buffer text to have text properties.

Comment: As best I can tell, so far, [`flx` is propertizing](https://github.com/lewang/flx/blob/master/flx.el#L378-L400) and [`flx-ido-mode` advises `ido-exit-minibuffer` to remove it](https://github.com/lewang/flx/blob/master/flx-ido.el#L244-L255) -- but _sometimes_ that doesn't happen. I haven't figured out the pattern, yet.

Comment: Thank you for the broader guidance. IIUC, things that set e.g. `buffer-file-name` ought to worry about de-propertizing text -- so that things that read/use it don't need to worry about that. Ideally.